# Setting property value in UserControl using JavaScript or Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

Guess I got this code behind,

```
namespace nn.ss.tt
{
    public partial class abc: UserControl
    {
        private string _MyProperty;
        public string MyProperty
        {
            get { return _MyProperty; }
            set { _MyProperty = value; }
        } 
    }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();
            }
        }
}
```

Now how can I set it's value here,

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
       prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
       prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

    });        

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) 
    {
       var hidField= $("[id$=_hidField]").val();

       // HERE I WANT TO set value of MY PROPERTY
    }
```

How can I do it sir ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly modify server controls' properties from the client side.
I would try adding aspnet hidden field to the page and modify its value from the client side. Then during a postback/callback after ProcessPostData lifecycle event the assigned value will be in Value property of your input field and you can set MyProperty from it.